# Why "No symbol file now" when I debug by gdb?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gdb

the Makefile is:

```
 objects = disk.o super.o inode.o namei.o open.o main.o

test : $(objects)
        cc -g -Wall -O2 -o test $(objects)

disk.o : fs.h disk.h
        cc -g -Wall -O2 -c disk.c

namei.o : fs.h
        cc -g -Wall -O2 -c namei.c 

open.o : fs.h
        cc -g -Wall -O2 -c open.c

super.o : fs.h
        cc -g -Wall -O2 -c super.c

inode.o : fs.h
        cc -g -Wall -O2 -c inode.c

main.o : fs.h disk.h sched.h
        cc -g -Wall -O2 -c main.c

.PHONY : clean
clean:
        rm edit $(objects)
```

I use the "-g" , but when I debug it by gdb:

```
gdb test
```

The message is:

```
Reading symbols from /root/lx/filesystem/lx_filesystem/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) file
No executable file now.
No symbol file now.
```

This is Why?
Thank you

Comment: Is `cc` a link to `gcc`? Besides, you shouldn't be working as `root`, if not necessary...

Comment: @bash.d  cc is ok when I test it . and I code in the VPS, so root maybe ok . Thank you

Comment: How did you compile the object files in the first place? if they weren't compiled with -g, you won't have debug symbols.

Comment: is there any -s or -S in the link line which are trying to strip.

Comment: @Dayalrai  I have show the all makefile and I don't use '-s' in anywhere. Thank you

Comment: @Entropia " cc -g -Wall -O2 -o test $(objects)", this '-g' can't create the symbols?

Comment: is it odd you don't specify the .c files as being dependencies for your .o files?  perhaps my makefile is rusty

Comment: You are only linking the compiled object files in the above Makefile. You have have compiled the source files before, there you have to specify `-g`.

Comment: hi @Entropia I have updated by "   cc -g -Wall -O2 -c disk.c" ,But it't not work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to confirm whether or not you have debug symbols in the binary. On Linux, you can run

```
file test
```

which should tell you whether the symbols have been stripped or not. Or try

```
nm -C test
```

to see a list of the symbols contained in your test binary. If you see something like

```
nm: test: no symbols
```

then that's the problem. If they haven't been stripped, then maybe your debug symbols are not gdb-style (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244509/no-debugging-symbols-found-when-using-gdb)).

Answer (score 1):

Your `Makefile` is incorrect in several ways. This should work better:

```
objects = disk.o super.o inode.o namei.o open.o main.o
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -O2

test : $(objects)
disk.o : fs.h disk.h disk.c
namei.o : fs.h namei.c
open.o : fs.h open.c
super.o : fs.h super.c
inode.o : fs.h inode.c
main.o : fs.h disk.h sched.h main.c

.PHONY : clean
clean:
        rm test $(objects)
```

But that wasn't your question. This:

> (gdb) file
>   No executable file now.

is happening because you are *resetting* file you want to debug to *nothing*. Don't do that.

You real problem is this:

> Reading symbols from /root/lx/filesystem/lx_filesystem/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

Why no debugging symbols? If your executable was built with the `Makefile` you provided, it should have had debug symbols. The only logical conclusion then is that it wasn't. What likely happened is that you've modified your `Makefile`, but didn't re-make, and are still debugging an *old* executable that was built without `-g`.

Using the fixed `Makefile`, and `make clean all` should

- Rebuild all your object files with `-g` (and you should see that they are rebuilt with `-g` in `make` output.
- Give you an executable with debug symbols.